# Can I choose where to publish my NPM module - either to the public or a private repo?

Tags: node.js, npm

We have recently started using a private NPM repository at work.  I also write various modules that are hosted in the main public NPM repo. The private repo does **NOT** replicate up (it just replicates down). Is there any way to specify to which repository I want to publish an NPM package?

Naturally, I want to publish work stuff to our private NPM repository and open-source modules to the public repository.

My ~/.npmrc file looks similar to this (obviously, values are taken out)

```
_auth = AUTH_TOKEN
email = MY_EMAIL
registry = URL_FOR_PRIVATE_REPO
```

Having done a bit of Googling, I found things like [this](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/100), but it does seem rather out-of-date (it's closed 2 years ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the package.json file:

```
{
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry":"https://private.internal.registry.mycompany.local/"
  }
}
```

The `npmrc` stuff is a bit tricky to manage.  We're working on rewriting a bunch of stuff so that all those configs will be scoped to a specific registry, but it'll be a while before that's done.